# Animation doesn't work when attached to the parent (RelativeLayout)layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, translate-animation

I tried to animate the button from top to a fixed position on the screen, it worked, when clicklistener was added on the button, but it doesn't get worked while attached to the relativelayout. So that the button including relativelayout get animated. I think the problem is when attaching layouts within nested viewgroups, Please help me with a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
 b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simpleButton);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.startAnimation(animations());
        }
    });
    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout.setAnimation(animations());
        }
    });
}


private TranslateAnimation animations() {
    TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0, -40);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return translateAnimation;
}
```

Here is the XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
     <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/wrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#cbcbbc"
android:layout_height="60dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/simpleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Go next page" />
   </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post `xml` layout.

Comment: What you want to achieve and what happens?

Comment: when i press the button, the layout comes from the top and gets into its position, similarly i want to achieve that with the whole layout including the parent layout. It only works on the button click, not on the relativelayout click

Comment: `new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0, -40)` will animate your button from its current position to 40 pixels top. But you claim that "comes from the top and gets into its position". Cannot see how that may happen.

Comment: sorry i just got it wrong. any way the animation doesn't work while clicking on the relative layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Instead of:

```
relativeLayout.setAnimation(animations());
```

Do this:

```
relativeLayout.startAnimation(animations());
```